# Creating Remote Methods at run time?

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

- We got ourselves into a situation where we want to create 'Remote Methods' at run time using loopback? So that any client can create his own secure route at run time without the need to reload the server.
- Also how can we add ACL to the remote method added during run time?

Answer (score 1):

First the *remote methods are added at runtime*, though at boot up. And you can define them in your `model.js` present at `common/models` folder. You can check them here in the [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+methods). Try adding the remote method and show your code if any problem.

Second you can add ACL to your code in two ways:

- Using DataSource's `createModel()` function:

  `var Customer = ds.createModel('Customer', { 
      name: { 
          type: String, 
          acls: [ 
              { principalType: ACL.USER, principalId: 'u001', accessType: ACL.WRITE, permission: ACL.DENY }, 
              { principalType: ACL.USER, principalId: 'u001', accessType: ACL.ALL, permission: ACL.ALLOW }
          ]
      }
  }, {
      acls: [
      {principalType: ACL.USER, principalId: 'u001', accessType: ACL.ALL, permission: ACL.ALLOW}
      ]
  });`
- In your case, you could use ACL's `create()` function in `model.js`

  `ACL.create({principalType: ACL.USER, principalId: 'u001', model: 'User', property: ACL.ALL, accessType: ACL.ALL, permission: ACL.ALLOW}, function(err, acl) {...});`

  `ACL.create({principalType: ACL.USER, principalId: 'u001', model: 'User', property: ACL.ALL, accessType: ACL.READ, permission: ACL.DENY}, function(err, acl) {...});`

You can read about adding ACL at runtime here in the  [docs](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB1/Advanced+topics).